# How to copy file from remote system to local system using C# (connected in same LAN network)?

Tags: c#, file, remote-access, wmi-query

Two computers are connected in same LAN network. I am trying to copy a file from remote system to my local system using C#. But I cannot able to copy the file from remote system. But I can able to make copies in the remote system itself.

This is to execute WQL (WMI Queries) in the remote system

```
ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM CIM_DataFile WHERE 
       FileName='test' AND Extension='txt'");
ManagementObjectSearcher  searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
queryCollection = searcher.Get();

ManagementBaseObject inParams, outParams;
string localPath = "C:\\Users\\UserName\\Desktop\\log.txt";
string remotePath = "\\\\RemoteComputer\\C:\\Folder1\\Testing\\test.txt";

foreach (ManagementObject m in queryCollection)
{
    // Display the remote file information in local system 
    Console.WriteLine("Name         :{0}", m["Name"]);
    Console.WriteLine("File status  :{0}", m["Status"]);
    Console.WriteLine("File Type    :{0}", m["FileType"]);
    Console.WriteLine("Object Name  :" + m.ToString());

    Console.WriteLine("\nFile copying has been initiated ...");

    // Method - 1
    using (FileStream localDest = File.OpenWrite(localPath))
        using (FileStream remoteSource = File.OpenRead(remotePath))
        {
            remoteSource.CopyTo(localDest);
        }

    // Method - 2
    File.Copy(remotePath, localPath, true);

    // Method - 3
    inParams = m.GetMethodParameters("Copy");
    inParams["FileName"] = localPath;
    outParams = m.InvokeMethod("Copy", inParams, null);

    Console.WriteLine("Return value :" + outParams["ReturnValue"]);
    Console.WriteLine("\nFile copying completed !");
}
```

But the code is copying file from remote system to local system. I can able to make copies in the remote system, but cannot able to copy that to my local system

Comment: There are lot of confusions in your question so it is not clear what exact issue you are facing... you have 3 methods in the code to copy files from remote machine to local machine. Which method you are facing problem with? What problem you are facing? Are you getting any error? What error? What is the exception message?

Comment: In the method 1, I am getting error like invalid path parameters. And method -2 also the same error. In method-3 the return value is 9

Comment: Your remote path is wrong.  There should not be a colon (":").

Comment: try replacing `:` with `$`. `"\\\\RemoteComputer\\C$\\Folder1\\Testing\\test.txt"`. Are you able to do `\\RemoteComputer\C$` from Windows Explorer?

Comment: All the three method are not working. Can you suggest me some ideas ?

Comment: No. I cannot able to access the \\Remote\C$ from my local computer

Comment: Thank you so much. I found it. I enabled the remote share in remote system and then I ran the File.Copy (remoteShare, localPath, true) command to do the rest

Answer (score 0):

Your remote path looks like a UNC path.

\\REMOTESERVER\SHARENAME\Path\to\file.txt

Where SHARENAME is a shared folder. Windows automatically creates special admin shared folders for the drives on your machine with a $ suffix, so you have C$ mapping to the machines C: drive.

Your remote path should therefore be something like:
\\RemoteComputer\C$\Folder1\Testing\Test.txt

You need admin rights on the remote machine to access such a share on a remote machine, or you can create named shares with custom permissions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I enabled the admin$ in my remote machine and then in cmd  I called "net use \\remote\Windows" method to grant access to that path (\\RemoteComputer\Windows). Now my method is copying the file from remote system to local system. (---File.Copy(remotePath, LocalPath, true)-----)